# I can't import kivy in python

Tags: python, kivy

I use `windows 10 64-bit`, `python 3.6`, `pip 8.1.2` and `kivy 1.9.1`. `kivy`was installed according to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#windows-run-app).

After installing `kivy` I can't import it as I get this error

```
ImportError: No module named 'kivy'
```

How can I solve this I searched many times and followed the steps and it ends up with the same problem

Comment: Python 3.5 is currently not supported on Windows due to issues with MinGW and Python 3.5. Support is not expected for some time. See this issue for details. If required, 3.5 MSVC builds should be posssible, but have not been attempted, please enquire or let us know if you’ve compiled with MSVC. source:- https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#installation-on-windows                                                                                                             If you want you can use `python 3.4`also if possible post the cmd output

Comment: Actually I don't know what is MSVC but what I made is the steps in the link you wrote only the 3 steps in comand prompt

Comment: MSVC is microsoft visual c++. like i said kivy doesn't support python version greater than 3.5. install python 3.4 then install pip kivy cython and follow the installation docs. don't forget to rum the cmd as administrator also check for error messages and find the reason for those and solve them

Comment: Ok I will try it and reply to you again

Comment: If you don't need 3.5+, go for the lower version. Then you don't even need to compile, because there are [wheels](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#nightly-wheel-installation) for `master` branch and a simple `pip install kivy` for stable version. Ofc with dependencies installed. Also, try [KivyInstaller](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller) if you encounter problems on your system(such as DLL errors).

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the latest pip and wheel:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
```

Install the dependencies (skip gstreamer (~120MB) if not needed, see Kivy’s dependencies):

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew

python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
```

Note

If you encounter a MemoryError while installing, add after pip install an option

```
–no-cache-dir
```

.

For Python 3.5+, you can also use the angle backend instead of glew. This can be installed with:

```
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
```

Install kivy:

```
python -m pip install kivy
```

(Optionally) Install the kivy examples:

```
python -m pip install kivy_examples
```

The examples are installed in the share directory under the root directory where python is installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but if anyone stumbles on it the answer can be found here:
[trying to install kivy on my pc i get the following errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016957/trying-to-install-kivy-on-my-pc-i-get-the-following-errors/42036104#42036104)

All the convenience of wheels can be found with 3.6 now as well as with older versions