# trying to install kivy on my pc i get the following errors

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, kivy

tried installing kivy on my pc with python 3.6. using cmd and both pip and easy_install i got the error

"Cython is missing, its required for compiling kivy !"

then i tried installing cython and i got

"Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools"

and i have visual studio fully installed on my pc
when i visited the link giving above, the file i downloaded asked me to first uninstall my visual studio before i can install it. which i cant!

any solution?

Comment: Is your visual studio version up to date?

Comment: Check if VS in your PATH: `VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\` If not - try to add it.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to install directly from the wheel.  For 3.6, the easiest way would be to follow the instructions to install the nightly wheel, since 3.6 builds are relatively new and this is one way to find them.

https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

I used this path....painless to have kivy with python 3.6